# Office Addins : How to handle 'The license information for this add-in is missing or expired. so it may have limited functionality' warning?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, appsource

One of my office add-ins for Excel/Word/PowerPoint is published in the Microsoft AppSource, But the users are reporting that they are getting a warning message when they open the add-in after installing it.

[image: Reference image for the Warning Message]

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Could someone from Microsoft please reply to this?  I am having the same issue, and I can't find any information about how to fix this.

Comment: Can you  folks please provide in what office version and build you are experiencing this?

Comment: (1) Could you add your manifest file (with ID and URI's masked, if you wish) to your question? (2) What happens if you try deploying in other user machines? Does the issue happens only for the given user or for any user downloads from store? (3) Had it worked anytime successfully earlier for this user? (4) Try taking fiddler and see what you notice in it.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

1. Remove all the addins & clear the cache:

- Remove all sideloaded add-ins from Excel, Word, and PowerPoint, delete the contents of the folder:

> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\

If the following folder exists, delete its contents too:

> %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\AC#!123\INetCache\

2. Now run the application and load the addin
3. If issue persists, then try enable the runtime logging

Enable runtime logging - by [following the steps][1]!!

4. In addition, i would collect fiddler to see if they provide any clue. Also will try to sideload the manifest and see if it works.
   [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtime-logging